# How To Package an A Python Application for easy access of modules

Tags: python

I have a python app which includes several modules packaged in different directories.

What I want is to be able to define the root directory(or otherwise) and be able to call packages from There-- The way django works. I haven't been able to get very usefull information on this and any suggestion would be very welcome

Am having a structure like:

`/main`

```
     dir1

         __init__.py

         subdir2

             __init__.py

             module1.py

             module2.py

         subdir3

             __init__.py

             module3.py

             module4.py
```

I want to be able to do the following from `module3.py` :- `from dir1.subdir2.module1 import *` and be able to do `from dir1.subdir3.module3 import something` from `module1.py`

Comment: Can you give us the directory structure you're looking to use, and maybe some code to show the way you'd want your app to be able to access your modules? It's tough to tell exactly what you're looking for with the current wording of the question.

Comment: I have edited accordingly @MarkHildreth

Comment: From what I can see there is no problem with that structure, except the use of `*`. what error are you getting?

Comment: Currently am unable to import module1 from module3 for example.. That's really the issue @myusuf3 and not really a syntax error :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should have `/main` in your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. Or in your main program you do:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/main')
```

But if you are running a recent version of python you should consider doing relative imports using `from ..subdir3.module3 import something` in `module1.py`